# What were the German words spoken by Stormfront?

Tags: the-boys

In the last part of the episode 2x08 of The Boys, Stormfront begins to speak in German.

What were her final words?

Comment: IMHO this is trivia: it merely shows her reverting to her true self. From what little she says it seems to be an anecdote, possibly about her child, something about an apple tree.

Comment: @BCdotWEB : Well since I don't speak German (and I'm assuming the asker doesn't either) it is very much possible that her words could have a some meaning, in relation to either the future or the past. Or maybe some character development, of some sort. So classifying this as trivia works only for those who speak German, and a complete mystery for those who don't. The subtitles simply say "[SPEAKING GERMAN]" which ain't helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Screenrant.com](https://screenrant.com/boys-season-2-finale-stormfront-german-meaning/):

> Reddit user Raidoton helpfully transcribed and translated the full text of Stormfront's dialogue, revealing that Stormfront was recalling a beautiful moment with her husband and daughter, as they sat in the shade of an apple tree. When Homelander arrived, she apparently saw him as her husband and said, *"Do you remember the day Frederick? Chloe's arms out of the car window. We found the perfect spot by the river, in the shade of an apple tree. It was the first time Chloe ate fresh apples."* Later, she muttered to herself, *"It was so wonderful. I wanted it to never end."* It might have been a sweet, sad moment, if you ignored that the memory was coming from a woman trying to start a race war with an army of superhuman soldiers.